# How to pass arguments to constructor if object is loaded dynamically with Loader in flash?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Is this possible ? If yes how ?

Otherwise what's the alternatives ?

By dynamically I mean using

```
    loader = new Loader();                      
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, finishLoading);
    loader.load(new URLRequest("MySWF.swf"));
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your question a bit? Clarify your meaning of "dynamically". Are you talking about a factory method, or are you speaking of something else entirely?

Comment: see my update I mean using Loader

Comment: Ah. Are you specifically trying to load a SWF and set its parameters? A SWF isn't a class object, so it shouldn't have a "constructor" per se.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A SWF is not a class by itself, more like a collection of classes and other things (like images or audio bytes) all archived and ready to use. You can't have a constructor for a SWF. However, what you can do, is loading a SWF and then, after the loading is complete, you can instantiate a class from that SWF and pass whatever arguments you want to it's constructor.

Also, it's possible to send parameters to the SWF and then process them as flashvars inside the swf, but that's no constructor of course :)

```
loader.load(new URLRequest("MySWF.swf?day=tue&week=3"));
```

And then you can get them like this:

```
var paramObj:Object = LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters;
trace(paramObj.day);
trace(paramObj.week);
```

Comment: Thanks how "instantiate a class from that SWF and pass whatever arguments you want to it's constructor"

Comment: well, let's say you have a 'Train' class in that SWF, after you load the swf that class becomes available like any other class so you can simply do `new Train(power)` where power it's the variable you need to pass to `Train` constructor. However, if you need to pass variables for the entire SWF, I guess the second option would be better.

Comment: but what is Train is the code behind a fla. If I create a new instance of Train while passing color OF BACKGROUND for example, will the swf BACKGROUND reflect that color ?

Comment: Train it's a class in that SWF, like any other class, after you instantiate it , you can use it (for example, add it to the child list). However, if you want to change the color of a instance inside the SWF (like background instance for example) you simply:

`loader.content.background.setColor(0xCCCCCC);`

Where loader it's your Loader class, and background is a class with a custom method, setColor, implemented by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a document class in your SWF, then rather than using parameters in the constructor create a public init method with your parameters, or even use getters and setters:

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;

public class MySWF extends MovieClip
{
    private var _var1   :String;
    private var _var2   :int;

    public function MySWF():void
    {

    }

    public function init(var1:String):void
    {
        _var1 = var1;
    }

    public function get var2():int
    {
        return _var2;
    }
    public function set var2(value:int):void
    {
        _var2 = value;
    }
}
```

Then you can call these after you have loaded your swf like this:

```
private function finishLoading(event:Event):void
{
    var mySWF:MySWF = event.target.content as MySWF;
    addChild(mySWF);
    mySWF.init("This is a string");
    mySWF.var2 = 5;
{
```

Comment: Thanks if not possible with constructor I'll do that but I prefer constructor.